# Probability at least one bolt in a sample of four is identified as incorrectly torqued

Tags: probability, sampling

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

*Question 2:*
Assume the following characteristics of the inspection process in Ex. 1 (see below). If an operator checks a bolt, the probability that an incorrectly bolt is identified is 0.95. If a checked bolt is correctly torqued, the operator's conclusion is always correct. **What is the probability that at least one bolt in the sample of four is identified as being incorrectly torqued?**

Now here is what ex. 1 says:
A steel plate contains 20 bolts. Assume that 5 bolts are not torqued to the proper limit. 4 bolt are selected at random, without replacement. to be checked for torque.

a) what is the probability that all four of the selected bolts are torqued to the proper limit? Answer: 0.282
b) what is the probability that at least one of the selected bolts is not torqued to the proper limit? Answer: 0.718

---

The answers of Ex. 1 make a lot sense and are pretty simple. I cannot figure out the answers or question in bold.. and there are no answers

Help please!

Comment: Hi Omar, welcome! Could you answer question 2 if you knew that, for example, 2 out of the four bolts are actually incorrectly torqued? The operator would check 2 good bolts and say they are good, and then you would need to calculate the probability that she or he finds out the incorrect torque for at least one of the bad bolts.

Answer (score 1):

here are some hints (it is not a complete answer):

In question 2, you have selected 4 bolts from the 20 bolts, and in the 20 bolts, there were 5 uncorrectly torqued ones.

So, there are all in all 5 possible situations when the operator comes into play:

- A: all bolts are OK, 0 bad ones
- B: 1 bad bolt,
- C: 2 bad bolts,
- D: 3 bad bolts,
- E: 4 bad bolts.

For all these situations, you can calculate the probability, because you know how to solve question 1. Thus you now have $P(A)=0.282, P(B)=0.470, \dots, P(E)=0.001$.
 <sup>For best results in the end, use more significant decimals</sup>

Now let F be the event that the operator identifies one or more incorrectly torqued bolts. You can in every situation calculate the probability that this happens.

- For situation A, F is not possible, because there are no bad bolts.
  One writes this as $P(F\mid A)=0$.
- In situation B, there is one bad bolt, and the operator detects it with probability 0.95. We write $P(F\mid B)= 0.95$.
- In situation C, there are two bad bolts. What is the probability $P(F\mid C)$? The result should be $P(F\mid C) = 1 - 0.05^2 = 0.9975$.
  ... and so on <sub>(it should be easy to find $P(F\mid D)$ and $P(F\mid E)$)</sub>.

The question asks for the *unconditional probability* $P(F)$. You need the [*law of total probability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) to obtain $P(F)$ from all the probabilities that you have calculated above.

The result I got is $P(F)=0.69$.